# Flux pattern to initialize Store

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Good Morning All!

I've a react Component (a View) that's dependent on a Store which is in turn dependent on having some state pulled from a round-trip to the server.

What I'm looking to understand is if there's a common pattern to solve for initializing the Store's state.

Right now I'm thinking I'd do something like:

```
var SomeView = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    SomeStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);

    // Go and tell this thing we want to initiliaze our
    // state ahead of time. My worry here is obviously 
    // that when state is updated this fires again so I'd
    // need to have some knowledge that the store has been
    // initialized which seems very (very) kludgey
    SomeActions.init();
  },

  render: function() {
    // Here i'd want to see if I had items available for
    // rendering. If I didn't I'd drop on a loading dialog
    // or if I did I could render the detail.
  },

  _onChange: function() {
     // this.setState...
  }
});


var SomeActions = {
  init: function() {
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: SomeConstants.INIT
    });
  }
};


var SomeStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, { 
  init: function() {
    $.get('/round/trip', function(data) {
      this.emitChange();
    }).bind(this);
  }

  emitChange: function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
});


AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
  switch(action.actionType) {
    case SomeConstants.INIT:
      SomeStore.init()
      break;

    default:
  }
});
```

I am absolutely positive there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

> My worry here is obviously that when state is updated this fires again

`componentWillMount` fires once component injected to DOM, state updates will not fire this method. However, if you remove component from DOM (for example: not rendering it in parent component based on some condition) and render it later, the method will be fired again. So `init` will be called multiple times on the store.

I believe you should move http request code to Web API module and fire an action to the API from `componentWillMount` method, the API will then trigger the store and fire `change` event on the component, which will update the state and re-render. This is how Flux works.

If you need to get data only once and you know your component is going to be removed from/added to DOM multiple times, you should put a call to the api into upper component in the tree (component that represents an entry point to the widget or something).

I recommend to check [Component Container](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750) or Higher-order Components pattern, which basically defines a thin wrapper component as a data layer over the view component. Thus you can completely separate your views from data layer and it works good.

You may also want to check another approach, coming from ClojureScript's Om, with a single immutable state. This simplifies everything even more and actually the best way I've found for my self to build apps with React. I've create [`a starter kit`](https://github.com/roman01la/f-react-kit) for it, there's a good explanation of main concepts in the readme.

Comment: Thanks @Roman - can you expound bit on 'the API will then trigger the store'. I can fire an action to a Web Api module and then after I've completed the round trip post the results back to the store then have the store emit the change?

Comment: @Cory Exactly. Just keep in mind that the api should update a store via action as well.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks for the tip and the links. I'll give this a go tonight.